# Mathematics in PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner here. I have two questions.

This is my query:

```
$result = mysql_query( "select SUM(achievenum) as achieve_rows from games" );
$row = mysql_fetch_object( $result );
$total_achieve = $row->achieve_rows;

$result = mysql_query( "select SUM(achieveget) as get_rows from games" );
$row = mysql_fetch_object( $result );
$get_achieve = $row->get_rows;

$completed_rate = $get_achieve * 100 / $total_achieve;
```

1. How can I make this code with one query instead of two?
2. When I display the percentage

it shows

```
Completion Rate : 32.3529411765%
```

I need it to show only the first three numbers.

```
32.3 %
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Ok Thanks For Posting This :) Iam Gonna Learn

Answer (score 5):

To modify your sql use this:

```
select 
    SUM(achievenum) as achieve_rows, 
    select SUM(achievenum) as achieve_rows 
from games
```

and to display the result, you want to format it first using round:

```
<?php 
    echo round($completed_rate,1)."%"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The query would be :

```
select ROUND(SUM(achieveget)*100/SUM(achievenum),1) as completion_rate from games
```

Comment: +1 for doing it all in MySQL ([as you should always do](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/06/23/mysql-has-functions-part-5-php-vs-mysql-performance/)) and in 1 SQL query